# Python: classes handling mutable variables in inherited classes which depend on parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class CommonParent(object):

    mutable_field = u'parent_replace'
    format_field = u'parent_format'
    full_pattern = u'{{to_replace}} {to_format}'

    pattern = full_pattern.replace(u'{{to_replace}}', mutable_field)   

    result_string = pattern.format(
        to_format=format_field            
    )

class Child1(CommonParent):

    mutable_field = u'child1_replace'


class Child2(CommonParent):

    mutable_field = u'child2_replace'
    format_field = u'child2_format'


class Result(Child1):

    pass
```

What is the pythonic way of achieving following result:

1. When Result inherits from Child2 - I would like `getattr(Result, 'result_string')` to show `child2_replace child2_format`
2. When Result inherits from Child1 - I would like `getattr(Result, 'result_string')` to show `child1_replace parent_format`

The problem is that Result class should be universal - code should work when this class inherits from Child1 or Child2. How to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to accomplish this. You can then override the necessary properties in the child classes to achieve your desired result. For example:

```
class CommonParent(object):

    @property
    def format_field(self):
        return u'parent_format'

    @property
    def mutable_field(self):
        return u'parent_replace'

    @property
    def result_string(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.mutable_field, self.format_field)


class Child1(CommonParent):
    @property
    def mutable_field(self):
        return u'child1_replace'


class Child2(CommonParent):
    @property
    def format_field(self):
        return u'child2_format'

    @property
    def mutable_field(self):
        return u'child2_replace'


class Result1(Child1):
    pass


class Result2(Child2):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r1 = Result1()
    print(getattr(r1, 'result_string'))

    r2 = Result2()
    print(getattr(r2, 'result_string'))
```

When this script is run, it outputs:

```
child1_replace parent_format
child2_replace child2_format
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using classmethod, not sure if it is ok, but it works.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class CommonParent(object):

    mutable_field = u'parent_replace'
    format_field = u'parent_format'
    full_pattern = u'{{to_replace}} {to_format}'

    @classmethod
    def setVariables(cls):

        cls.pattern = cls.full_pattern.replace(u'{{to_replace}}', cls.mutable_field)   

        cls.result_string = cls.pattern.format(
            to_format=cls.format_field            
        )

class Child1(CommonParent):

    mutable_field = u'child1_replace'


class Child2(CommonParent):

    mutable_field = u'child2_replace'
    format_field = u'child2_format'


class Result(Child1):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Result, self).setVariables()

result = Result()
print getattr(result, 'result_string')
```